# Accessing a .strings file that is inside a library, not bundle

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am inside a xcodeproj that is inside another xcodeproj or in other words a static library. This project contains multiple .strings files. This in particular is inside this library. How do I access strings inside this file?

- `NSLocalizedString(@"myText", @"")` gets strings from .strings on the main project;
- I cannot use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"myText", @"myTable", @"myBundle", @"")`, because the file (table) is not on a bundle. It is inside the library.
- `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"myText", @"myTable", @"")` gives me nothing.
- `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"myText", @"MyLibrary/myTable", @"")` gives me nothing.

now what?

Comment: "because the file (table) is not on a bundle. It is inside the library" - iOS project, so your only chance (almost...) is that it's a static library. In this case, you'll have a static library and all the resources will be copied to the app bundle. **It *is* in the app bundle.**

Comment: what do you mean? Are you saying that Xcode will copy that to the app bundle automatically?

Comment: What else could it do with it? (Read: yes, it will.)

Comment: Sorry but everything that can go wrong will go wrong with Xcode 4 that is the pinnacle of a crappy software... and no, it is not there, unless I copy it manually.

Comment: (that's why the seasoned iOS developer has been so much fed up with Xcode that he doesn't use it anymore.) Well, *where* is it then?

Comment: Sorry but the pain of using another tool and command line compiler is too much. The .string file is on the static library. I have tried now `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"myText", @"MyLibrary/myTable", @"")` without success. The strangest part is that when I type @"MyL and press ESC it autocompletes... and then autocompletes myTable after that. So, it sees the table there.

Comment: the code that needs to read the table is inside the static library or in other words, the codes that needs the string and the strings file are both on the static library but one cannot see the other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29777/discussion-between-h2co3-and-rubberduck)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  When the sub-project is built, the product is a static library.  This doesn't contain files, just object code.  There's no facility for bundling files inside the static library.

If you want a file from the sub-project to be in the final application bundle, you will need to add it directly to that project.